# Working with the registry on 64 bit system. framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-2.0, registry

How to get a list of subkeys in the **HKLM\SOFTWARE** in the 64 bit system?

**P.S.** If I use 
`Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\", false)`
then I get in **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node**

I can use the .NET Framework is not higher than 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems quite involved, and probably too much code to put here on Stack Overflow.

The summary is that you need to P/Invoke to access the native Windows API Calls for [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and make sure to pass in the flag KEY_WOW64_64KEY to always access the 64bit registry. (KEY_WOW64_32KEY being the flag to always access the 32bit one)

A partial solution has been posted on [this blog entry](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=915).

For anyone that can run .NET 4.0, then you can use the new support for this: [RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411615.aspx)(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

Answer (score 0):

You will get the registry for whichever architcture your app is running on or compiled for.
If you target x86 then you will always get the 32-bit registry ("Wow6432Node") on a 64-bit machine.
If you target AnyCPU, then you will get the real Software node for the machine's architecture.